# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields

Tags: php, sql-server

I want to update name and image using PHP Script with Stored Procedure in SQL Server. but the result showing like this

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields. in C:\xampp\htdocs\library-api\master.php:943

Here is my profile function on `master.php`

```
public function UpdateProfile($name, $image)
{
    // Statement
    $sqlsrvquery = "
    EXEC [dbo].[UpdateProfile]
    @name = ?,
    @image = ?";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sqlsrvquery);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $image, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { //the result error showing here
        $profile_arr[] = array(
            "status" => true,
            "message" => "Successfully Update Profile !"


        );
    } else {
        $profile_arr = array(
            "status" => false,
            "message" => "Failed to Update Profile",
        );
    }
    print_r(json_encode($profile_arr));
}
```

And here is my SP

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[UpdateProfile]
(
    @name varchar(50),
    @image varchar(MAX)
)
as
begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    UPDATE profile set name = @name, image = @image
END
```

I am already using `SET NOCOUNT ON` but its not working properly. Any suggestion of this code? Thanks.

Comment: You're calling `fetch` but your SP doesn't return any results? Either return some results or use `execute`.

Comment: Return value = 0 from SP

Comment: The return value isn't a resultset - you need a `select` for that. Also you SP isn't using the `return` statement - which is should.

Comment: ooo i get it. thank you